# How to debug a failing websocket connection in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I want to connect a websocket from a web app to a server on our enterprise platform, for this I created a simple frontend and a simple websocket server to try things out.

Unfortunately, the application does not work in Google Chrome, but it does work in Firefox. I can also connect to the websocket correctly via Postman.

This is the line I use to connect to the websocket:

```
const socket = new WebSocket("wss://<host>/ws");
```

I then get a console error which looks like this:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://<host>/ws' failed:
```

There is no mention of *what* went wrong, and there is no additional information in the error event object. Inspecting `socket` reveals `readyState = 3` as expected.

[image]

I've tried to get additional logs by launching chrome with debug logs like so:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-logging --v=9
```

But I only see the following line related to the error, nothing more.

```
[VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(34)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: wss://<host>/ws
```

Chrome version:

```
Google Chrome   99.0.4844.51 (Official Build) (x86_64) 
Revision    d537ec02474b5afe23684e7963d538896c63ac77-refs/branch-heads/4844@{#875}
OS  macOS Version 12.2.1 (Build 21D62)
JavaScript  V8 9.9.115.8
```

How do I debug this failing websocket connection? Why does it work in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer, maybe this helps you:

I have faced the same problem, and the actual solution was to disable the adblocker for the website that tried to establish the websocket connection to a server.

Maybe your adblocker is only installed on Chrome, thus working on Firefox and Postman.

Comment: @wilco Was this the accepted answer? I have also experienced this on several machines which do no have adblocker installed.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem but without any adblocker or other plugins running. This issue is only happening in Chrome, whereas Firefox and Insomnia (postman alternative) work 100% without issue.

I'm using a Spring Boot backend and stepped through the code to try and see what might be causing it. The embedded tomcat server seems to be expecting input from the connection but it does not and therefore disconnects. When I inspect the same method from my firefox connection, I get input:

WebSocket frame received. fin [true], rsv [0], OpCode [8], payload length [2]